# A word containing style with comma acts an selector eg:-"Style, "

Tags: javascript

If the word **style** with **comma** is used in a string value, and getting the value using the queryselectAll returns the style as an node. check below sample for reference.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x, i;
  var i = "Style, value as testing"
  x = document.querySelectorAll(i);
  debugger;
  console.log(x);
}
```

```html
<style>
  p {
    color: red
  }
</style>

<p>Click the button to check the queryselectorAll method</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
```

In the above sample, cick the try it button and check the console.

Is it the javascript behavior ?

Answer (score 1):

From the docs [Document.querySelectorAll(selectors)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) you specify "selectors" with the following rules:

> A DOMString containing **one or more selectors** to match
> against. This string must be a valid CSS selector string; if it's not,
> a SyntaxError exception is thrown. See Locating DOM elements using
> selectors for more information about using selectors to identify
> elements. **Multiple selectors may be specified by separating them using**
> **commas**.

Which means on the code you have

```
var i = "Style, value as testing"
x = document.querySelectorAll(i);
```

your selector(s) are `Style` and `value as testing` so you have 2 selectors. In the console you only see one node because the selector only found the `<style>` element.

Answer (score 0):

That's not JavaScript behavior per se, it's CSS behavior. `querySelectorAll` gets you all the elements that match a given CSS selector, and the CSS selector `Style, value as testing` would match

- `Style` elements
- and (`,`)
- `testing` elements whose parent is an `as` element whose parent is a `value` element.

Out of these two, you obviously only have a `<style>` in your document, so that's what you get.